# Simplify NinjectWebCommon RegisterServices with a Generic Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject.web

I'm using `Ninject.MVC3` for my `DI`.

I have more than 25 dependencies to inject, but my `RegisterService` now has 25 lines with simlar code like:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IClientRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IRegionRepository>().To<RegionRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IRequestTypeRepository>().To<SolicitudTipoRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<OrdenRepository>().To<OrdenRepository>();
            //Some other references....
        }
```

But, is possible create a generic repository (or repository interface) to inherit all my repos and only inject a generic class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well one way to do it is doing a query your assemblies by interface and implementation using reflection, you have to define which namespaces you would like to scan something like:

```
string[] namespaces = { "namespace1", "namespace2", "namespace3", "namespace4" };
//scanning assemblies
List<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("mybasenamespace")).ToList();
            foreach (var reg in assemblies.Select(assembly => (from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                                                               where !type.IsInterface && type.GetInterfaces().Any() && namespaces.Any(n => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains(n))
                                                               select new
                                                               {
                                                                   Service = type.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(type.Name)),
                                                                   Implementation = type
                                                               })).SelectMany(registrations => registrations.Where(reg => reg.Service != null)))
            {
                //do your registrations by type here kernel.bind etc, etc
            }
```

that way you are implementing **convention over configuration** and you'll avoid doing registrations one by one, it could be other ways but this strategy can be applied to any container you want to use.

Comment: I was just reading an article about `GetAssemblies` method:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be413ce1-5881-4668-acf5-7c8058fc7fcc/getassemblies-throws-serializationexception?forum=netfxbcl
But this codes should run when the project starts, right? Where I should create the method, in the `App_Start` directory or in my `Global.asax` ?

Comment: it's recommended to you do it while bootstrapping your application where you are setting up your dependencies to the container it could be either global asax or any other "place"

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to use the generic repository pattern.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ICacheRepository<>)).To(typeof(ICacheRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
```

Inside a controller, you need to specify the exact generic type, such as

```
protected ICacheRepository<MockDataSetEnum> LocalCache;

public PlayAreaController(ICacheRepository<MockDataSetEnum> LocalCache)
{
    this.LocalCache = LocalCache;
}
```